# Read file, and process words with Word class, method

Tags: java, string, class, file-io, cpu-word

I am trying to create a Word Class that processes every word that the file imports.

The Word Class needs to distinguish punctuation for the ending/beginning of sentences, increment valid words, and increment each syllable.

My problem is getting the scanner to pass the word onto the Word class for the methods to process them. the error is on "word = scan.next();." Error message is "incompatible types:Required Word, Found String."

Thank you for your help...

```
System.out.println("You chose to open the file: " +
            fc.getSelectedFile().getName());
            scan = new Scanner(fc.getSelectedFile());
            while (scan.hasNext()) 
            {
                Word word = new Word();
                word = scan.next();
```

Word Class

```
public class Word {
    private int wordCount, syllableCount, sentenceCount;
    private double index; 
    private char syllables [] = {'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u', 'y'};;
    private char punctuation [] = {'!', '?','.'};;


    public Word()
    {
        wordCount = 0;
        syllableCount = 0;
        sentenceCount = 0;
    }

    public void Word(String word)
    {
        if(word.length() > 1)
        {
            for(int i=0; i < punctuation.length; i++)
            {
                if(punctuation[i] != word.charAt(word.length()-1))
                {
                    wordCount++;
                }
                else
                    sentenceCount++;
            }
            for(int i = 0; i < syllables.length; i++)
            {
                for(int j = 0; j < word.length(); j++)
                {
                    if(syllables[i] == word.charAt(j))
                    {
                        syllableCount++;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(word);
    }
}
```

Comment: a `String` is not a `Word`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `scan.next()` returns a `String` not a `Word` object you can not assign it like that.

Try this:

```
while (scan.hasNext()) {
    Word word = new Word(scan.next());
    //...
}
```

To do this, you need a constructor like that:

```
public Word(String s){
    //...
}
```

Comment: that's a method signature, not constructor

Comment: @voe I tried the Word word = new Word(scan.next()); before and got error messages. I didn't even realize that my error was in the Class at that time. Thank you for the help...!